# AWK--Storing truncated values in arrays

Tags: awk

I have a formula in my awk script which outputs non-integer numbers with variable number of decimals. So, I was wondering how I can save the outputs with a certain number of decimals, say for example 2, in an array. As an example:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<10;i++){array[3/i]}}'
```

Comment: Can you show a simple example which illustrates your problem?

Comment: Just added an example. How I can fill "array" with numbers having only 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html):

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<10;i++){array[sprintf("%.2f", 3/i)]}}'
```

This will create an array with the following indexes:

```
1.00 
0.50 
0.33 
0.60 
0.43 
1.50 
3.00 
0.38 
0.75
```